# Windows 10 error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1

Tags: windows, compilation, gcc, linker

I am struggling to fix `error: linking with 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc; failed: exit code: 1`, I have installed TDM-GCC-64 and Cygwin and added them to PATH as well as updating the c++ 2019 redistributable. I am attempting to use GLFW or an alternative but when ever I try I to run the rust projects that use GLFW or its alternatives I get this error `note: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh` is there something else i'm missing. Thanks

Full error below

```
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.build_script_build.253ad390-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.3xe3r320o5t2g1tt.rcgu.o" "-L" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-9075868f02c39105.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-9428c324e8b3666b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libobject-4a98078f239020c3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libmemchr-6757767b31fe77e1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libaddr2line-c0d2da11c6d2d6c0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libgimli-9e7d4e8bc407ad15.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_demangle-da42fc4024365a2c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_detect-89ac367f33223d21.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libhashbrown-d506a327105b7f9b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-59684a51af165391.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-76b6cbab8df641fe.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcfg_if-1f71fd1e2c1fff1d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-941c197b7acaf3f9.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-ed65eeea771bb49a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-206ecc270c58e4f3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-1063c1f162c501e3.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-3f91c8bbaf203c3c.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lkernel32" "-lws2_32" "-lbcrypt" "-ladvapi32" "-luserenv" "-lkernel32" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-L" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-o" "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\Rust_Programming\\Code\\Opengl_Lessons\\learn-opengl-rs\\target\\debug\\build\\num-complex-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe\\build_script_build-1d9dcc0a2e0581fe.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "C:\\Users\\peter\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh
          collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: TDM, Cygwin, and 2019-redestributable are three different tool-chains. Similar, but different, you should not mix them. You need to choose one environment, meaning MinGW of TDM flavor, Cygwin, or Visual Studio. And stick to them. It is sometimes possible to reuse some pieces of tool chains, but not easy and require good understanding of both tool-chains.

Second: read the error message "ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh" - that means your linker cannot find a library gcc_eh. What is that library? Which project you are trying to compile?
Go to the projects documentation, find there installation instructions and do as written. This instruction will (most likely) have suggestion which tool-chain to use too.

Comment: Thanks, ill remove TDM then, I haven't found anything on lgcc-eh or which library it's from I'm trying to compile an example project from a rust implementation of OpenGL https://github.com/bwasty/learn-opengl-rs it recommends using the glfw library or glutin but both have the same error. They do recommend using CMake to compile GLFW myself but i didn't manage to do this.

Comment: @wilderdragoon48 libgcc_eh provides **e**xception **h**andling support I think; I wonder if this TDM-GCC patch [Reintegrate libgcc_eh into libgcc](https://github.com/jmeubank/tdm-gcc-src/blob/tdm-patches.public/_PATCHES/libgcceh.patch) is relevant?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your suggestion I ended up removing Cygwin and TDM and then installing MSYS2 and adding it to PATH and it solved the issue.